# How can I save a value to the database and / or modify database content as needed?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to insert articles in the database which are in the shopping cart, and if one goes back to the article list and comes back to the shopping cart, the shopping cart in the database an update should take place.
How can you do that?

I've already interviewed google.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("database.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['warenkorb'])){
    $warenkorb = $_SESSION['warenkorb'];
}else{

    $warenkorb = array();
}
$array = serialize($warenkorb);
if(!$id = $pdo->lastInsertId()){

$sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO warenkorb (id, array) VALUES ('', :artikel)");

$sth->execute(array('artikel' => $array));
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
}else{
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE warenkorb SET array = ? WHERE id = ?");
$statement->execute(array($array, $id));
}

?>
```

Comment: You can should be use here ajax method

Comment: Your question is not very clear. I think you should add more details. What have you tried. What is not working. What exactly should happen in this method.

Please note, that your code seems buggy to me. $pdo->lastInsertId() won't return any id, if no insert was performed previously.

Comment: found something: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE how to use it?

Comment: When I go from the shopping cart to the cashier, the array and a pimary key are to be inserted into the database.
If there is already an entry from this session, the database entry should be changed.

Comment: @mscho: In addition, no update takes place. Each time the script is called, a new entry is written to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well. In an ideal world the Shopping Cart would be an object containing references to its contents. ie:

```
$cart->hasItem($item);
```

But since you are trying to build it yourself there are two options. You can query the database if the item exist, which is not a terrible thing to do. Or use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html. The insert-on-duplicate can cause scalability or replication issues in the future.